# How to return zero if no rows exist in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have read other answers on this but can't seem to get it to work for me.

I am creating a new table but I want to put `0` in a variable if no rows exist

The code I have below returns a table like this:

```
 was_recalled  | total
```

It has empty rows.

What I want to happen in this case is for it to be like this

```
was_recalled    | total
Yes             |   0
```

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php 
    $barPrelimSql = "select was_recalled, count(*) as total FROM mark_cards1 WHERE school = '$ownerSchool' AND was_recalled = 'Yes' AND competition_level1 = 'Prelim Champion' GROUP BY was_recalled";
    $barPrelimRes = mysqli_query($con,$barPrelimSql);

    while ($barPrelimRow=mysqli_fetch_array($barPrelimRes)){
        $barPrelimR = $barPrelimRow["total"];



        ?>

  var dataLace = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Placement', 'Recalled', 'Not Recalled'],
      ['Prelim Champs', <?php echo $barPrelimR; ?>, 5],
      ['Open Champs', 5, 24],
      ['Majors', 54, 44],

  ]);

        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I know thank you. I just want to figure out how to get this to work and then I will go back through the site and change it.

Comment: You could change your `while ($barPrelimRow=...` to `if ($barPrelimRow=...` and put an `else { $barPrelimR = 0; }`. (Remember to change where the braces are for the `while()` loop though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using group by condition in the query that is the reason it will not returning 0 count when there is no rows present in your query.

In my suggestion you can check the num rows return by the query if the rows are zero then you can directly set it to 0.

```
<?php 
$barPrelimSql = "select was_recalled, count(*) as total FROM mark_cards1 WHERE school = '$ownerSchool' AND was_recalled = 'Yes' AND competition_level1 = 'Prelim Champion' GROUP BY was_recalled";
$barPrelimRes = mysqli_query($con,$barPrelimSql);
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($barPrelimRes);
if($row_count > 0){
    while ($barPrelimRow=mysqli_fetch_array($barPrelimRes)){
        $barPrelimR = $barPrelimRow["total"];
        var dataLace = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Placement', 'Recalled', 'Not Recalled'],
              ['Prelim Champs', $barPrelimR, 5],
              ['Open Champs', 5, 24],
              ['Majors', 54, 44],

        ]);
    }
}
else{
    $barPrelimR = 0;
    var dataLace = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Placement', 'Recalled', 'Not Recalled'],
          ['Prelim Champs', $barPrelimR, 5],
          ['Open Champs', 5, 24],
          ['Majors', 54, 44],

    ]);
}
```

?>

Comment: Man, thank you so much! I tried everything else and this seemed to do the trick! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just verify if the mysqli_fetch_array return NULL .

> **mysqli_fetch_array** : Returns an array of strings that corresponds to
>   the fetched row. NULL if there are no more rows in result-set

```
$results= mysqli_fetch_array($barPrelimRes);

if(is_null($results)){
$results = ["was_recalled"=> "yes", "total"=> 0];
}

// code
```

Don't forget to update your code to avoid sql injection.